# SQL COUNT get zero

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalStudent,
c.* 
FROM classroom c 
INNER JOIN student s
ON c.classID = s.classID 
GROUP BY c.classID
```

How to get zero in `totalStudent`?  if student empty inside the classroom.

Comment: You could use `coalesce(count(*), 0)`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as:  "Some classes have no students.  How do I include these?"  If this is correct, then the key is `left join`:

```
SELECT c.classId, COUNT(s.classId)
FROM classroom c LEFT JOIN
     student s
     ON c.classid = s.classid
GROUP BY c.classId;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for the grammar. 
SELECT c.classId, COUNT(s.classId)
FROM classroom c LEFT JOIN
     student s
     ON c.classid = s.classid
GROUP BY c.classId;

output:
classID 1,2 | COUNT(s.classID) 4,6 ... 
but the classID 3 did not show

Comment: @BenjGonzales . . . I would then conclude that "3" is not in the table `classroom`.

Comment: i have a problem whenever I add new 'classes' once I saved it. The number of student inside the class became 1 but there is no student inside it yet. It should be zero

Comment: @BenjGonzales . . . The `count(s.classid)` with the `left join` should return `0` in this case.